# AssertionFailedError: null ==> expected: not <null>

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I created a testing class for my service implementation. All tests of other methods of this class are being tested, and Mapper is also used in these methods, but one method of this class does not pass the test and throws an error. What could be the problem?

```java
@Test
public void testCreateParcel() {
    ParcelDTO parcelDTO = new ParcelDTO();
    parcelDTO.setId(1L);
    parcelDTO.setClient(new Client());
    parcelDTO.setDepartment(new Department());
    parcelDTO.setStatus(Status.NEW);
    parcelDTO.setWeight(1.0);

    when(parcelRepository.existsById(anyLong())).thenReturn(false);
    when(parcelRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(new Parcel());

    ParcelDTO result = parcelService.createParcel(parcelDTO);

    assertNotNull(result, "Result is null"); //I get null here
}
```

```java
@Override
public ParcelDTO createParcel(ParcelDTO parcelDTO) {
    if (parcelRepository.existsById(parcelDTO.getId())) {
        throw new AlreadyExistsException("A parcel with this ID already exists ", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    Parcel parcel = mapper.convertValue(parcelDTO, Parcel.class); //mapper non convert this

    Parcel savedParcel = parcelRepository.save(parcel);
    return mapper.convertValue(savedParcel, ParcelDTO.class);
}
```

I tried logging, inserting blocks of code like this:

```java
if (parcel == null) {
    create new exception IllegalArgumentException("Not converted to DTO");
}
```

and I was getting my error about not converted DTO.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ParcelServiceImplTest {
@InjectMocks
    ParcelServiceImpl parcelService; //.....
```

Comment: How do you create your `mapper`?

Comment: Parcel, ParcelDTO and the Mapper are all missing, it is impossible to tell you what might be going wrong without all the moving parts.

Comment: @QBrute  RequiredArgsConstructor private final ObjectMapper mapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Comment: Can you update your question to show:
1 - How you are creating the `ParcelService` in your test.
2 - The constructor of the `ParcelService`

Comment: @user2131323 is that what you meant?